# What's the correct syntax for variable replacement when using a custom predicate in a stored Fetch Request?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

[In this SO question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897068/variable-substitution-with-fetchrequests-stored-in-a-coredata-model), the OP asks how to go about formatting a stored fetch request created in the Xcode GUI to allow for variable substitution when the stored request is called at runtime using NSFetchRequest:fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:substitutionVariables.

Apple has some [archived documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-219639) that talks about how to do this in Obj-C, but Swift handles variables differently and I haven't found the syntax documented anywhere.

In my application, I'm looking to find an audio track that belongs to a certain category.  The track has an attribute called `trackCategory` which is defined as an `Int64`

In my template Fetch Request, I've set up a Custom Predicate with the statement `trackCategory == $TRACKCATEGORY`.  As I understand it, I'm setting up a condition where the object will only be returned if the object's `trackCategory` value matches a variable value named `$TRACKCATEGORY` that will be substituted at runtime.

[image]

And then, in my code, I'm trying to call this stored fetch request as follows:

```
fetchRequest = model.fetchRequestFromTemplate(withName: 
"getUnplayedTracks", substitutionVariables: ["TRACKCATEGORY" : forCategory])!
```

Two things:

1. `model` is declared at the top of the ViewController (this document) as:

`let model = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.managedObjectModel`.

2. `forCategory` is an Int64 declared elsewhere.

When I build and run this, I get a SIGABRT with the error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unable to resolve variable expression: $TRACKCATEGORY'

I'm sure I'm missing something with how the Custom predicate statement is formatted, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Can you share also your code from making url object to init your model object?

Comment: sure...I've added it to the question text.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't.... really see any wrong with your codes. Have you tried turning it off and on? Just kidding. On a serious note, try restarting your Xcode? Clean build? Clean project? These might help.